# Average of one column based on conditions (in different columns)

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

First the code:

```
library(dplyr)

#Sample Data

df1 = cbind(c(replicate(5, 2015)),
                        c(replicate(5, 1)),
                       c(rnorm(5, 0, 1)),
                       c(replicate(5, 'A')))

df2 = cbind(c(replicate(5, 2015)),
                       c(replicate(5, 2)),
                       c(rnorm(5, 0, 1)),
                       c(replicate(5, 'A')))

df3 = cbind(c(replicate(5, 2016)),
                       c(replicate(5, 1)),
                       c(rnorm(5, 0, 1)),
                       c(replicate(5, 'B')))

df = rbind(df1, df2, df3)

# Code I used    
bs1 = file %>% 
      group_by(V1) %>% 
      group_by(V2) %>% 
      summarise(avg = mean(V3[V4=1])) %>% 
      ungroup()
```

Problem statement: I want to average col `V3` for each `V4` and `V1`. For instance, for 2015, all the 1's under `V3` should be averaged. Similarly, all 2's should be averaged separately. In essence, instead of 5 rows in 2015 for 1's and A's, there will be just one (it's average). Similarly, instead of 5 rows for 2's and A's, there will be just one.

The actual data frame is much longer with 365 `V3` entries for each of the 7 `V4` entries each year (from 2015 to 2020).

```
# Desired Output
# Calculation not accurate (just an example of how the output should look like)
> new_df 
V1    V2    V3    V4
2015  1   0.02456  A
2015  2   0.04533  A
2016  1   0.07821  B
```

Thanks,
Rahul.

P.S. I don't know if my question is clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(V1, V2, V4) %>% 
  summarise(mean_V3 = mean(V3))

# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   V1, V2 [3]
  V1    V2    V4    mean_V3
  <chr> <chr> <chr>   <dbl>
1 2015  1     A      -0.185
2 2015  2     A      -0.290
3 2016  1     B       0.364
```

---

*Data*

```
df1 = cbind(c(replicate(5, 2015)),
            c(replicate(5, 1)),
            c(rnorm(5, 0, 1)),
            c(replicate(5, 'A')))

df2 = cbind(c(replicate(5, 2015)),
            c(replicate(5, 2)),
            c(rnorm(5, 0, 1)),
            c(replicate(5, 'A')))

df3 = cbind(c(replicate(5, 2016)),
            c(replicate(5, 1)),
            c(rnorm(5, 0, 1)),
            c(replicate(5, 'B')))

df = rbind(df1, df2, df3) %>% as_tibble() %>% mutate(V3 = as.numeric(V3))
```

Comment: wow! Now that you have done it. It looks so easy. Thanks, Dominik.